# Are these mushrooms that popped up in my plant pot problematic?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health, mushrooms

As I went to water my plants today, I was surprised to see that a few mushrooms have sprouted in the same pot as my pepper plant. I was of the impression that mushrooms needed a dark place to grow, but as the pot is located on the windowsill of a southern window, that didn't seem to bother these mushrooms (though to be fair, winter is just over, so it wasn't super bright either).

Now, visually, they don't bother me, but I don't know if they're a problem for either my plant or my health. So far, the plant seems unbothered, but the mushrooms have also just peeked out of the earth at most a few days ago.

Can anyone, therefore, identify the mushrooms below?
For further reference: I live in southern Germany but, as the pot is always indoors, this doesn't influence weather conditions other than light level.

[image]

Comment: note: regardless of the identification (which I'm aware is unlikely to be 100% correct if done online with just a picture), I do not intend to eat the mushrooms, to be on the safe side in case they're poisonous. I'm just curious if their general presence in my apartment is harmful.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that mushrooms don't require light (as opposed to requiring darkness) and commercial mushroom culture is typically done in the dark to reduce competing things that need light. I've been picking little mushrooms out of one batch of tomato seedlings for weeks (not to eat) without apparent ill-effects on the tomatos.

Answer (score 3):

No they're not harmful to you or your plant - it means the potting soil you used contains mycelium, and these mushrooms are just the fruiting bodies off that. The only possible problem is if you have a sensitivity to fungal spores, which the mushrooms will release within 3 or 4 days of appearing, so if you're not sure,just snap them off at the base using a plastic bag over your hand and dispose of them. I am not sure whether these are edible or not...